# Google Translate an image, not on your phone

Tags: google-workspace, images, google-translate, ocr

The Google Translate application now supports in-image OCR and translation of text:

https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142483?hl=en

but this functionality does not seem to be accessible using a PC and visiting `translate.google.com`.

How can I get it to work for files on my PC (with no Android phone)?

Note: People somehow assume I have Google Drive, or a Google Account etc. I never said that.

Comment: Google prefers proprietary Apps over a standards based web interface (for anonymous user) because of data collection. I doubt there is a web interface.

Comment: @FyodorGlebov: I was assuming their app was _using_  a web interface somehow...

Comment: it uses some undocumented API

Comment: @FyodorGlebov: If you know that for a fact, make it an answer please.

Comment: You also never said you wanted to avoid requiring a Google Account.

Comment: Did anyone else find it quirky that the app wants permission to your camera, in order to tranalate an image sitting in storage?

Comment: After checking all the answers here, the easiest option for me was to take a photo of my screen with my phone.

Answer (score 26):

Not Google, but similar.

Yandex Translate has image upload using desktop web browsers.

https://translate.yandex.com/ocr

I use this in a [Flotato](https://flotato.com) browser which enables me to quickly translate screen grabs without them accumulating on my hard drive (because the screen grab is automatically deleted after I've dragged it onto the Yandex/Flotato window).

Afterwards you can use the foreign text from Yandex (Open in Translate button) with alternative translation services like [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com) or [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com).

Also: on the latest macOS, you should be able to extract foreign text from an image and translate it.

Comment: Yandex translator really saved my day. Unfortunately it can't save translated image, but I solved it by taking a screenshot.

Comment: At least in October 2022 the translator yandex website linked above can save the translated image (tested on desktop PC)

Answer (score 14):

The purely Google approach I use is:

1. Upload the image to your Google Drive
2. Right click image and choose *Open with > Google Docs*

> A new document will be created containing the image and extracted text

3. In Google Docs choose *Tools > Translate document...* and choose your target language

> A second document will be created with the translated text

Done!

Comment: "Your Google Drive" <- I don't have a Google account. But I guess this is reasonable advice for someone who has.

Comment: @einpoklum my solution achieves "Google Translate" or Translation using Google services.

Comment: Thank you for showing this option, but this should be possible to do without a workaround, shouldn't it? Don't know what are they thinking at Google, why it works on Android but not on web. Gonna use Yandex for that.

Answer (score 3):

First, change your Google Drive setting, if necessary (maybe back again afterwards), to check *Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format* ([see](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112373/60716)).

Upload your image file to Google Drive, open it and choose Tools > Translate document... and the language of your choice (from those available!) then click <kbd>Translate</kbd>.

As an example I selected a snip (.JPG) of Article 1 of the *Universal Declaration of Human Rights* in Persian from [Omniglot](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/persian.htm):

[image: Arabic script]

and the result (in a different file) for English was:

[image: Translation]

with the top (Arabic) as an image and the bottom (English) editable text (note cursor).

Comment: Um, what Drive settings? Don't you need a Google account for that?

Comment: OK... I was hoping to avoid having a Google account, but I guess I can't complain.

Comment: Ok, found the action, but a below answer helped me more saying we're actually creating a Google Docs file where they start to interpret the text (OCR) in the image.  I'm not here to change an entire drive setting.

Answer (score 1):

The Translatium desktop app allows image upload.

You may be lucky to find a download of this app, because it was discontinued. Why? The unofficial API it uses can sometimes fail. My solution is to simply try again a minute or two later and it usually goes through OK.

https://translatiumapp.com/