# Converting all PNG images in Google Drive to text (OCR)

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, ocr, file-conversion

I found Google Drive the best OCR for Persian texts. The problem is Google Drive doesn't convert files larger than 2MB so I can't use big PDFs.

So I extracted all pages from PDF into PNG images.

Now, how can I tell Google Drive to convert all of my PNGs in a specific folder into Google Documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Google Drive and Settings (the cog) and Settings (the text):

[image: WA108954 first example]

you should be able to check:

[image: WA108954 second example]

to have the conversion be automatic on upload (along with the uploaded image).

Comment: Didn't work for me