# Google Translate Issue

Tags: google-translate, ocr

I have issue that when I use google translate in mobile phone it is able to use import picture and convert it to the text, but the using Computer by Chrome or Firefox browser it cannot use it like mobile phone.
How to get the Khmer text from picture in google translate on PC?
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Posible duplicate: [Google Translate an image, not on your phone](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107953/88163)